# Tint2 do not startup when Unity boot in first time

Tags: 14.04, unity, startup-applications, tint2

I use tint2 in my Ubuntu 14.04, but it didn't startup in the first time when I logging my user. I have to EndSection Section and re-entry again for tint2 appear.

Tint2 is in my startup applications.

I have tried to remove and re-install tint2, but the problem continue.

Is there an solution for that?

Comment: EndSection Section is when you log out and log in in the same account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tint2 dev here. From what you say it sounds like tint2 crashes the first time it is launched after boot. Hard to say why as I have not seen other reports of this.

Unfortunately the version packaged in Ubuntu is quite old; you could try removing it and compiling from source the latest one: https://gitlab.com/o9000/tint2/wikis/home

Comment: so it is outdated?

Comment: The package uses the previous release from 2012. In the meantime I fixed a lot of bugs and released a new version a few days ago.

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to use the packaged one, it might help to add a delay to make sure tint2 starts after the desktop has initialized completely. For this, instead of having the command `tint2` in startup applications, use `sh -c 'sleep 3; tint2'`